# Mosfet part number? How to find a replacement otherwise?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet, motor-controller

[image: Picture]

I did a quick google search based on the numbers on this Mosfet and found nothing. How would you go about finding a datasheet and replacing a part like this?

```
GP7NabOHDa  
CCos1  
MRC - 502
```

This part is located on an Ametek 1000W blower. I believe it is used to control the speed of the motor.

Comment: never, ever, ever, ever loosen a retaining clip or a screw and let it drop and just leave it there. one day you will get distracted and forget about it.  then you know exactly what will happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misread the part number. This is an [ST GP7NC60HD](http://www.st.com/en/power-transistors/stgp7nc60hd.html) IGBT.

Steps I took to identify this:

- Recognize the ST logo (lower left).
- Go to [st.com](https://www.st.com/).
- Type the recognizable letters "GP7N" into the search bar; the rest of the part number is suggested as a search result.

Comment: I think that it might be a STGP7NB60H, not a STGP7NC60H

Answer (score 2):

The best place to search for a partial part number is [findchips.com](https://www.findchips.com/).  If you put in a partial number, it returns parts that have the specified text anywhere in the part number.

I put in a [search for "gp7n"](https://www.findchips.com/search/gp7n) and came up with the [STGP7NB60H](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ST%20Microelectronics%20PDFS/STGP7NB60HD(FP).pdf), which looks like it may be your part.  It also looks to be no longer available.

There is the [STGP7NC60H](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/a3/53/c7/8a/50/8d/47/18/CD00044166.pdf/files/CD00044166.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00044166.pdf), which looks like a higher current lower Vcesat version of the part.  Not sure if it would work as a replacement, especially if there are multiple instances of the part and the circuit assumes that they have similar characteristics but you are changing only one.

[image]